# ABCpdf9 Html output not working

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, abcpdf9

I am creating an HTML table using WebSupergoo ABCpdf9 :

```
string htmlSample = "<table border='1'><tr> <td>Current Address</td> <td>Optio distinctio Sed vel quasi <br /> 281<br /> Mollitia ea qui adipisci voluptas, IL, 66293<br /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>email</td> <td>demo@me.com</td> </tr> <tr> <td>dob</td> <td>8/18/2006 12:00:00 AM</td> </tr> </table>";
```

then

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
doc.AddHtml(htmlSample);
doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;  //<-- also tried this as well
```

[image: Generated PDF]
The PDF has **no table rows/columns** or boarder when generated.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddHtml is for multi-styled text.

AddImageHtml is for true HTML/CSS web pages.

AddHtml is used for multistyled text. It's very fast. However it doesn't support HTML - it supports an HTML-like syntax - it supports HTML styled text. The key tags it doesn't currently support are img and table. It doesn't support CSS. It is designed principally for multi-styled text using an HTML-like syntax.

AddImageHtml is used for full HTML/CSS rendering. It's rather more sophisticated and complex but not as fast. It supports all tags including img and table. It supports CSS. It supports JavaScript. It supports everything you get in real-world web pages. You can use either the MSHTML engine for IE-like behavior and display or you can use our Gecko engine for Firefox-like behavior and display.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and contacting tech support at websupergoo.com, here is the solution.

Do not use for styled html (anything)

```
doc.AddHtml(htmlSample);  <-- does not render html correctly
```

Use

```
doc.AddImageHtml(htmlSample);  <-- works.
```

I guess the method name threw me off.